# BeautifulSoup doesn't return any value

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautifulsoup and seems to have encountered a problem. The code I wrote is correct to my knowledge but the output is empty. It doesn't show any value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")

nifty = soup.find_all("span", {"id": "lastPriceNIFTY"})

for x in nifty:
    print x.text
```

Answer (score 1):

The page seems to be rendered by javascript. `requests` will fail to get the content which is loaded by JavaScript, it will get the partial page before the JavaScript rendering. You can use the [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for this like so:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sess = dryscrape.Session()
sess.visit("https://www.nseindia.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(sess.body(), "lxml")
nifty = soup.select("span[id^=lastPriceNIFTY]")
print nifty[0:2] #printing sample i.e first two entries.
```

Output:

```
[<span class="number" id="lastPriceNIFTY 50"><span class="change green">8,792.80 </span></span>, <span class="value" id="lastPriceNIFTY 50 Pre Open" style="color:#000000"><span class="change green">8,812.35 </span></span>]
```

Comment: I cant install dryscrape. it is giving me errors every time i try to install it via pip. can you help?
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/webkit_server'

Comment: @Himakar Are you windows or linux?

Comment: I am on windows 10.

Comment: @Himakar Install Anaconda package if you can. It has most of the dependencies. Then try to install dryscrape.